# Probabiltiy theory: show independence and distributions of r.v.'s within floor functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

**PROBLEM**

---

Let $X\in\text{Exp}(1/\lambda)$. Invoking again the integer part (i.e. *floor function*),

\begin{align}
\lfloor x\rfloor \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \text{the largest integer smaller than }x,
\end{align}

we set

\begin{align}
L_{m} = \bigg\lfloor \frac{X}{m}\bigg\rfloor 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
R_{m} = X - m\cdot L_{m}.
\end{align}

Let $m\geq 2$ be an integer. Show that $L_{m}$ and $R_{m}$ are independent r.v.'s. Determine even the marginal distributions of $L_{m}$ and $R_{m}$.

---

Here I define the exponential probability distribution $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ as

\begin{align}
f_{X}(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}} \quad 0\leq x,\\0 \quad \text{elsewhere}. \end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}

So finding the distribution of $L_{m}$ I can do: we first realize that $L_{m}$ must be a *discrete* r.v. because of the floor function which eliminates the decimal part. I write

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(L_{m}=l) = \mathbb{P}\left(\bigg\lfloor\frac{X}{m} \bigg\rfloor =l\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(ml\leq X \leq m(l+1)\right) = \int_{ml}^{m(l+1)}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = e^{-\lambda ml}(1-e^{-\lambda m}) = (1-p)^{l}p \sim \text{Ge}(p)
\end{align}

where we have cleverly rewritten the expression using $p=1-e^{-\lambda m}$.

As for $R_{m}$ I am not so sure: we realize that $R_{m}$ can only be in the interval $[0,m)$ since if we have that $X$ is a multiple of $m$ then we will obtain $R_{m}=0$, and if $X$ is just below a multiple of $m$ then $R_{m}$ obtains its highest value which can be made arbitrarily close to $m$. So how do I find $R_{m}$? It seems I have to use a different approach than before.

Furthermore, how do I prove that they are independent in this case? I don't know how to apply the transformation theorem in this case, is it possible?

**Edit**: is $X$ and $L_{m}$ independent? If so, how do I prove that? It just seems reasonable judging from the distributions.

So I solved the problem. Here is the solution: we realize that $R_{m}$ maps $X$ from inside the (disjoint) intervals of multiples of $m$, i.e. $I_{k}=[km,(k+1)m)$, to $[0,m)$. So we may write

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(R_{m}\leq r) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(km\leq X\leq km+r) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{km}^{km+r}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = \{1-e^{-\lambda r}\}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda km} \\[6mm]
&= \frac{1-e^{-\lambda r}}{1-e^{-\lambda m}}.
\end{align}

Now, to show independence between $L_{m}$ and $R_{m}$ we need the joint distribution, but it is not given. However we may compute it using some (yet again) clever observations, namely that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(L_{m}\leq l, R_{m}\leq r) = \sum_{k=0}^{l}\mathbb{P}(km\leq X \leq km + r) = \dots
\end{align}

which are just disjoint events, thus we employ the additive property of probabilities. Furthermore,

\begin{align}
\dots &= \sum_{k=0}^{l}\int_{km}^{km+r}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = \{1-e^{-\lambda r}\}\sum_{k=0}^{l}e^{-\lambda km} = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda r}}{1-e^{-\lambda m}}\sum_{k=0}^{l}e^{-\lambda km}(1-e^{-\lambda m})\\[6mm]
&= \frac{1-e^{-\lambda r}}{1-e^{-\lambda m}}\sum_{k=0}^{l}(1-p)^{k}p = F_{R_{m}}(r)\cdot F_{L_{m}}(l).
\end{align}

**QED**